# Does the 2008 Report Viewer control support running reports from a 2000 SQL Server Reporting Service

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reporting

I'm trying to verify whether or not you can run reports against from the 2008 Report viewer control against a 2000 SQL Server report server.  There's not a lot out there on microsoft's sites about what versions it supports.  I know it supports 2005 reporting services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the 2008 report viewer control does not support 2000 Report services because the 2005 control did not even support 2000 report services.